# Instagram API returning 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: ios, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, instagram

I am developing an iOS app which utilizes Instagram's API. Everything was working fine, though this morning, I started to get a Bad Request (400). My only guess is that in deleting and rebuilding my app over and over, it now appears "spammy" to Instagram, so they'v shut me down, as per this warning:

```
"You may also receive responses with an HTTP response code of 400 (Bad      Request) if we detect spammy behavior by a person using your app. These errors are unrelated to rate limiting."
```

I've even tried creating a different client app, using a different Instagram user, and using that clientID and URI in my app, but I am still getting a the 400.

Any ideas for a way around , this? I've contact Instagram support, but who knows when I might here back. Cheers!

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, what is your redirect URI you're using? here is my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898044/instagram-api-prevents-redirection-to-ios-app-upon-successful-login

Comment: any update on this ? Even in Android it is throwing 400. it was working fine previously

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there have been tons of problems with instagram logins, tags, etc...over the past 24-48hrs...

http://downdetector.com/status/instagram/news/53399-problems-at-instagram